# Android Notification AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-notifications

My AlarmManager does not seem to be working.

This is my code for setting up the alarm:

```
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Notify.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
```

This is my `Notify` class:

```
   public class Notify extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final int uniqueID=3657554;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder n=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    n.setAutoCancel(true);
    n.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    n.setTicker("ticker");
    n.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    n.setContentTitle("title");
    n.setContentText("text");
    Intent it=new Intent(context,ListAll.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, it,0);
    n.setContentIntent(pi);
    ((NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(uniqueID,n.build());
}
```

}

And I have the following in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<receiver android:name=".Notify" android:enabled="true" />
```

I don't have any exceptions but the notifications are not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to set the alarm

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20); // '8pm'
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Is the first alarm suppose to be triggered at `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` or is it 24 hours after that? I tried your code with the time changed but the notifications are not showing.

Comment: The alarm in my code launches at 8pm and repeats every 24 hours, you can change its time as you want

Comment: hey you, i have to problem, when change time at settings of device. Alarm no true time when i set 8pm. Can you help me.